# Make a facebook achievement visible in timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I can successfully publish a Facebook Achievement, but it only apears on my activity log.
There I  have the option to change its visibility from "Allowed on timeline" to "Shown on timeline" or "Hidden from timeline".
When I change it to "Shown on timeline" it apears on my timeline, and that's the default behaviour I'd like to happen.

**How can I change the default behaviour to "Shown on timeline"?**

I'm using Unity (latest version: 5.4.2) and Facebook SDK for Unity (latest version: 5.1).
This is the relevant piece of code:

```
var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
query["achievement"] = achievementUrl;
FB.API("/me/achievements", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, callbackfunc, query);
```

---

Also, I wanted something similar for the Score, but in this case it is even worse.
When I publish a Score it just says in the activity log that I was playing game X - it doesn't even say I have a new highscore.
The code:

```
var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
query["score"] = scoreString;
FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, callbackfunc, query);
```

---

[Edit] - The score "story" is apearing in the activity log as well after all, so the problem is exactly the same as the achievements.

Comment: You aren't using `query` anywhere. Doesn't seem to be the problem, but still.

Comment: You are right, I guess I cleaned up the code to much before posting, but the query parameter is in fact in my original code (I have big inline delegate functions, so I missed the fact that it had another argument after).
Question edited, thanks.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook says:

This behavior is intended for the Achievement story and it's not meant to be shown on Timeline.

I recommend moving away from these implicit stories and integrate explicit stories where the user decides how and when to share back to Facebook.

Here's a guide on how to implement explicit sharing: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.2#explicitsharing